# How to use the conjunction "as"?

Tags: conjunctions, grammatical-number

Are these correct uses of AS:
"What do you do AS a job?", 
"What do you do AS A leisure/sport activity?", "What do you do AS sport activitiES?"

meaning: "What job do you do?", "What leisure/sport activity/activities do you do?"

Comment: We would more naturally say "What do you do for a job?". Incidentally, "as" is a preposition, not a conjunction

Comment: You also might say: "What do you do as a physicist?" and when rephrased: "As a physicist, what do you do?"

Comment: In your examples, the word "as" isn't a conjunction. It is a preposition.

Comment: So you mean that these sentences are not said at all, aren't they?